# React Export a Multiple Level Table to CSV File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I have a React table like this. Do we have anyway to export this table to CSV file and keep the same structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but how easy it is really depends on how the underlying state is being stored in your app.

The [`react-csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv) package allows you to pass it an array of data and add a Download button to your site, but you first need to arrange/collect the data into the right format for it.

Comment: You're right the important thing of this problem is setting up the data to the right expected format.